# Trying to remap middle-mouse to Windows key

Tags: windows, windows-8, logitech-mouse, windows-key

I'd like to map the Windows key to my middle mouse button on my Logitech mouse, to swap in and out of the metro interface. You can assign keys to any of the mouse buttons in the Logitech software but I cannot get the Windows key to remap because when you click in the box and press it, it takes me into Metro like it's supposed to. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: May be [autohotkey](http://autohotkey.Com) may help you out with it.

Comment: Try [uberOptions](http://uberoptions.net) with Logitech SetPoint, or [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm).

Answer (score 3):

SetPoint saves the settings in a file called "user.xml" located in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Logitech\SetPoint`

There you can edit the mappings directly and test them after a restart.
The syntax for custom buttons is:

```
Ctrl is ^
Shift is +
Alt is %
Windows Key is *
{KEYNAME} for all direct keypresses.
```

So for example to map a Mouse-Button to change virtual desktops you can use the following:

```xml
<Button Number="4" Name="5">
   <Param IconLoc="" Type=""/>
   <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
      <Param Button="4" EventType="100663297" FirstRepeatDelay="0" RepeatDelay="0" Silent="0" Type="0"/>
      <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="KeystrokeAssignment">
         <Handler Class="KeyStroke">
            <Param KeyName="^*{LEFT}"/>
         </Handler>
      </TriggerState>
   </Trigger>
</Button>
```

Source: https://tinkertry.com/logitech-multiple-desktop-mouse-mappings-for-windows-10

- *Thanks to Rob Traynere for additional information*

Comment: You don't happen to know what the modifier keys are for ALT & SHIFT are, do you?  (you list ^ for CTRL & * for WIN)

Comment: Found it!  SHIFT is + ; CTRL is ^ ; ALT is % ; WIN is *

Comment: @RobTraynere thank you I've added this information to the answer

Answer (score 0):

In SetPoint, set the function of the button to be **Other** / **Start Menu**. That appears to have the same effect as pressing the Windows key.

Comment: Does SetPoint support all mouse?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was to set it as a macro. You can insert the windows button if you check under "Insert Special Keys" I did it with the microsoft mouse and keyboard center

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I wasn't able to follow your directions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to map the Windows Key to a mouse button is by using X-Button Mouse Control. When mapping the mouse button, choose the Simulated Keys option. In the Enter Custom Keys field, enter {LWIN} or {RWIN}. Click OK then Apply.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Option:
edit
the default options in default.xml in the folder "C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP"

Search for OEMOthersMiddleMiceGroup and make the following change

```
    <HandlerSetGroup Name="OEMOthersMiddleMiceGroup" HandlerSetNames="CloseApplication,Copy,Cut,Do Nothing,DoubleClick,StartMenu,DragLock,GenericMouseButton,LeftMouseButton,Maximize,Minimize,PageDown,PageUp,Paste,Redo,Unassigned,Undo,Windows8OthersTaskGroup" />
```

add the option that is missing "MiddleMouseButton"

```
    <HandlerSetGroup Name="OEMOthersMiddleMiceGroup" HandlerSetNames="MiddleMouseButton,CloseApplication,Copy,Cut,Do Nothing,DoubleClick,StartMenu,DragLock,GenericMouseButton,LeftMouseButton,Maximize,Minimize,PageDown,PageUp,Paste,Redo,Unassigned,Undo,Windows8OthersTaskGroup" />
```

Save the document and restart setpoint
[Exit Setpont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9WR6.png)

Start set point again and select the option in the menu

[Select MiddleMouse from settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zeIo.png)